cloudflare - I want to create new page rule from my nodejs Application
I want to create new page rule from my nodejs Application
I am trying with below code which i got from online but I am getting error that is
cf.pageRules.add('*', pageRuleSettings)
^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
const Cloudflare = require('cloudflare');

const cf = new Cloudflare({
    apiEmail: '****@gmail.com', // This is the default and can be omitted
    apiKey: '******', // This is the default and can be omitted
});

// Define the page rule settings
const pageRuleSettings = {
    targets: [
        {
            target: 'url',
            constraint: {
                operator: 'matches',
                value: 'mydomain.com/', // Enter your URL pattern here
            },
        },
    ],
    actions: [
        {
            id: 'forwarding_url',
            value: {
                url: 'www.mydomain.com', // Enter your destination URL here
                status_code: 302, // Choose 301 or 302
            },
        },
    ],
};

// Create a page rule
cf.pageRules.add('*****', pageRuleSettings)
    .then(response => {
        console.log('Page rule created successfully:', response.result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error creating page rule:', error);
    });

